# Have I got my account of my devices connected properly?

Tags: sync, microsoft-account

I've got a Windows phone (Lumia 950) and three laptops all supposedly running the same Microsoft account. However I don't seem to see the same data appearing all four devices. Is there some setting that I might have missed that could be stopping them all syncing? I've got them all logging in on the email address (blah@outlook.com) but they just don't seem to sync properly.

Could I be missing something?

Comment: What sort of data is not appearing on all four devices?

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain a list of devices connected to your account on [Microsoft's website](https://account.microsoft.com/devices).

1. Go to [this](https://account.microsoft.com/devices) website and login to your Microsoft account.
2. You should see something like this.

[image]

3. You can see the complete list of devices by scrolling down the website.

Comment: You see all my devices do show on my account but seetings and data seem to sync. Now I'm wondering if I've not got them set up properly.

Comment: @Kotch If you see all your devices on your account and all the data seem to sync(your comment says so) then what is the problem?